# Infopath Date Picker

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, infopath-rules

Im new to Sharepoint and using Infopath Designer for my list creation. i have requirement, in list i have 10 Date field, user has to select 1st date other 9 dates will be auto populate that i did.Now, problem is there is Days difference between 2 dates. like "2Date is 1Date + 5. and 5 is business days only not saturday or Sunday. E.g 1date is 12/18/14 then after 5 days 2Date should 12/25/14. like that for all dates. Can u please give me logic for it.

Comment: if you add 7 days to a date, that will give you five business days.

Comment: ma'am, this can't work. user can select any date from calender. so how we could predefine that..?? if user has selected Date1 as 12/18/14 then +5 workind days 12/25/14. like that if user has selected Date1 as 12/22/14 then Date2 should be  12/26/14 like that. considering only working days.

Answer (score 1):

Neither SharePoint nor InfoPath support the notion of "business days". In fact, both SharePoint AND InfoPath are not very good at handling dates and differences between dates. Adding "business days" into the mix won't make things easier.

You may want to explore a SharePoint Designer workflow to set the dependent dates, or maybe use a jQuery approach (but that won't work with InfoPath).

InfoPath for SharePoint list forms does not have good date handling. At all.

You would need code for that, but list forms don't do code.

Your best bet short of a custom code solution is a SharePoint designer workflow to add days to the date.

Comment: Thank you very much teylyn, and One more thing, is there any sequence in execuation of action rule. because on Date picker I'm applying 3 rule as necessarly required. bt i need only 2 rule should run, as whose condition will meet. bt all rules are execuating leading to wrong result. can u please tell me any solution..??